# How can I download all observations from Hue/Hive output?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

I am struggling with such a problem. My output table after executing a query on Hue/Hive has 1,2 mln of observations. When I try to download results as an `.csv` format there is only a possibility to download firt 1 mln of observations. I know that I can execute a query, select firs 0,9 mln of observations and download results and then execute a query to extract last 0,3 mln of observations and download results and merge then in for example R statistical package. But maybe anyone knows how to do it in a single approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy solution for this would be to save the output in a HDFS directory and then download data from there.Use a query like this to store the results:

> insert overwrite directory "$path" select * from ...

Answer (score 2):

You could bump the limit to more than 1 million but beware it might slowdown Hue: https://github.com/cloudera/hue/blob/master/desktop/conf.dist/hue.ini#L741

An alternative is to do a CREATE TABLE AS SELECT ... (this will scale but won't be CSV by default)

Comment: But create table doesn't solve the problem that I would like to download the set :)